# datatable fnRender

Tags: jquery, datatable

I have problem with dataTable fnRender. I used it to change my cell value from value to input with value.

My part of code:

```
{ "sTitle": "Cena netto",
              "fnRender": function(obj) {
         var sReturn = obj.aData[ obj.iDataColumn ];   
         sReturn = "<input type='text' id='Tcena_nettoZ_"+obj.aData[0]+"' class='cena_n'  name='Tcena_nettoZ_"+obj.aData[0]+"' value = '"+sReturn+"'/>";

         return sReturn;
         }
```

Now how can I change value other cell in this row when I change this value? 
I add class to this input but code :

```
$('.cena_n').change(function(){alert('a');});
```

Not work.

Comment: Just an FYI: `fnRender` is being deprecated and should no longer be used. If you're using 1.9.x, use `mRender`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your `alert('a');` isn't working is because that element doesn't exist at document ready .... you need to use delegated events.

try:

```
$('#your-table-id').on('change', '.cena_n', function() { alert('a'); });
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, [`change`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) is not the function you want to use.

To modify the value of an `input` tag, you should use [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) :

```
$('cena_n').val( 'newValue' );
```